# I logged into my work computer with my personal email, can my employer see my google search history on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, internet

Stupid mistake here. Today at home using my work computer I logged into my gmail on Chrome to check my personal email. I then went to look something up in google and saw several google search suggestions that I only typed in on my home computer; I don't have sync on, but I guess google searches are shared between devices if you're logged in on the same google account.

Is there any way for my work to see my google search history. I double checked and it doesn't seem websites/all browsing history or anything is shared, it's just that in Chrome google autofills certain past searches whenever I type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you didn't actively visit any of those sites on your work computer and assuming that you are now logged out of your google account on that computer then your employer has no way to view that browsing history as it is stored on your google account not locally. The only way that they could see it is if they logged into your google account.

If you did visit any of those sites on your work computer then your employer could see that history.

Comment: Yeah the only thing showing up on the work computer were google autofill searches (for example, when you type a letter into the google search bar and google brings up past searches); so my employer can't see that information? Could they decrypt network traffic or something and find these autofill suggestions? I've since logged out of my google account and don't log into gmail on my work computer.

Comment: Like anything computer related it's possible. They could have recorded and saved all network traffic an have someone dissecting that that likely encrypted network traffic to make out what your internet history was. But they won't because it costs an absolutely ridiculous amount of money and time to do so for no gain. It's kind of like how any encryption can be broken if you have infinite amounts of money and time to throw at it.

Comment: @AaronEngler, indeed, other ways would be screen-recording, or watching your monitor on CCTV. It would be interesting to test this - log in at home with work Google account credentials, check that search suggestions are there from past activity at work, log out of work Google account and then see if the home Chrome still has suggestions (eg in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default`). It seems possible that each new account connected Chrome would add the past suggestions in to the current suggestions database and cache that locally; that database can probably be viewed by your employer easily.

Answer (score 1):

The answer  here is nuanced, but the short version us "no, they cant"

There are 2 different types of search hiatory - those recalled by your PC and thise remembered by Google.

The ones in your PC are.local to the PC, and dont go iver the network so cant be read across the network.

The ones.sent to google are protected via HTTPS encryption in transiy. Unless your work added a cert ti your computer, or you accepted a message saying Google was insecure your work would not have been able to interpret the information between you and google.